# How to do the TEXT fade-in effect upon scroll down

Tags: jquery, text, scroll, fadein

I need a small help on loading Text With FADE-IN effect upon scroll down. I found a plug-in for loading fade in effect for Images ( like Mashable.com ), but i am requiring same for TEXT.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @動靜能量 said, one part of your solution is using the `fadeIn` method.
The other part is writing the code into `$(window).scroll(function (e) {})`

Check out the scroll api http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

And you might also want to use this:

```
(function ($) {
    jQuery.fn.scrollOffset = function () {
        var win = $(window);
        var topSpace = this.offset().top - win.scrollTop();
        var bottomSpace = win.height() - this.height() - topSpace;
        var leftSpace = this.offset().left;
        var rightSpace = win.width() - this.width() - leftSpace;
        return { top: topSpace, bottom: bottomSpace, left: leftSpace, right: rightSpace };
    };
})(jQuery);
```

This gets the scroll offset of a certain element.

Hook it all together and you should be able to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any plugin to fade in text.  You can just use jQuery's fadeIn()... something like

```
$('#my-div').fadeIn();
```

to fade in a div with id="my-div".  http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/